# Is it appropriate to use KPM and dotnet cli tooling side by side?

Tags: dnx, kpm, dotnet-cli

I'm in the process of experimenting with migrating to an ASP.net 4.6 site to DNX.

At the time of writing it's early days for the tooling in general.

I've read that dotnet cli aims to replace [KRE, KVM, KPM](http://gunnarpeipman.com/2014/10/asp-net-5-what-are-kre-kvm-kpm/). However is it appropriate to use kpm along side dotnet command line tools? I'm attempting to diagnose some troubles I'm having but [kpm seems to have more diagnostics functionality](http://davidfowl.com/diagnosing-dependency-issues-with-asp-net-5#diagnosingfailures).

Comment: No. kvm/kre/kpm were replaced by dnx, dnvm, dnu. The caveat is that dnx, dnvm and dnu are going away in favor of [dotnet CLI](https://github.com/dotnet/cli)

Comment: Thanks @Pawel it's tricky to be certain of what is up to date info as things are moving so (awesomely) fast. If you re-post your comment as an answer I'm happy to give it a ✓ (I see your at Microsoft - keep up the great work the new stuff is very exciting!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kvm/kre/kpm were replaced by dnx/dnvm/dnu. However dnx et al. is going away in favor of [dotnet CLI](https://github.com/dotnet/cli). For now, until dotnet CLI and matching ASP.NET Core is released use rc1-final and stick with dnx.